# Ruby on Rails 4 - Simplify concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, concatenation

How I can simplify this method?

```
def concat_arg(a, b)
  if b.any?
    a.concat(b)
  else
    a
  end
end
```

Comment: Make `A` and `B` lowercase. Also, what classes are you expecting?

Comment: I expecting String class

Comment: Why you need a method? Code `a.concat(b||'')` can do the same thing in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about B being nil you could do something like

```
def concat_arg(A, B='')
  A.concat(B)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to add a string to the end of an array, you don't need concat, which is mostly used to add the content of one array to another. Try this:

```
["apple","potato"] << "onion"
# => 
["apple","potato", "onion"]
```

Or, to handle the conditional:

```
foods << food if food and !food.blank?
```

You may find you don't need this method, it depends what you're trying to achieve.

Note: this behaviour may be different in ruby 2.x, have a play with it first to check how it handles nils